# Show full reputation on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, reputation-display

As soon as you hit 10k reputation the reputation is truncated to `xx.x k`.

On mobile unfortunately, after expanding the informationbar on the top, this forces you to perform another click to your profile page in order to check if anything has changed.

I'd like to see the detailed reputation (or having a notification in the top right corner) in order to save a click (and the sometimes long wait for the profile page) and bandwidth.

I'm aware that this may cause issues for people like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

However, the top space is not in use at the moment and the close button is completely redundant (at least I never use it), so this space could be used as well.

[image: mobile view]

Comment: This change would also be a useful in the profile page in the listing of rep on all linked sites. The abbreviation begins at 1k making it harder to look for changes across all sites.